# configure crontab job use Anaconda python packages

Tags: python, cron, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda on my server.
However, when I setup a cron job to schedule a script, it uses the default python installed on the system.

How do I use the Anaconda version?

This is my current cron job:

```
01 00 * * * python /home/ubuntu/data_scripts/test.py
```

Comment: This possibly has more answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365801/run-a-crontab-job-using-an-anaconda-env even though it's newer

Answer (score 1):

If you know the **installed path**, you can define your python path to your crontab.

For example, if the installed path is `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python3` your crontab would look like this:

```
01 00 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ubuntu/data_scripts/test.py  
01 00 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/data_scripts/test.py
```

Note: As @[asmeurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161801/asmeurer) mentioned, if you are using ubuntu your **installed path** probably will look more like this `/home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: The absolute path to the Anaconda Python is probably `/home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/python`.