# run a crontab job using an anaconda env

Tags: python, bash, cron, anaconda, conda

I want to have a cron job execute a python script using an already existing anaconda python environment called my_env.  The only thing I can think to do is have the cron job run a script called `my_script.bash` which in turn activates the env and then runs the python script.

```
#!/bin/bash
source activate my_env
python ~/my_project/main.py
```

Trying to execute this script from the command lines doesn't work:

```
$ sh scripts/my_script.bash
scripts/my_script.bash: 9: scripts/my_script.bash: source: not found
```

What do I need to do to make sure the proper environment is activated. Its ok to explain it to me like I'm 5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't call `sh` but `bash`. `source` is a bash command.

```sh
    - sh scripts/my_script.bash
    + bash scripts/my_script.bash
```

Or just

```sh
    chmod +x scripts/my_script.bash
    ./scripts/my_script.bash
```

since you added the bash shebang.

Comment: Is there an update to this, now that `conda activate my_env` is preferred over `source activate my_env`? I'm having trouble...

Comment: I don't use conda. I suppose you can use either sh or bash, then.

Comment: Figured it out. In my bash script, I run `source /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/activate` then `conda activate my_env`, vs. the `source activate my_env` in the original script.

Answer (score 25):

After MUCH fiddling I got `crontab` to activate my conda environment with `conda activate my_env` and run the Python interpreter within that environment.

Note I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

**Background**

- When the Anaconda installer initializes conda, it appends a snippet at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file. This file is executed each time the user opens `bash` interactively. The snippet allows the user to run `conda` commands (ie `conda activate my_env`) from `bash`.
- Anaconda installer v2020.02 appended the following **`conda` snippet in `~/.bashrc`**:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

- *The path `/opt/anaconda3/` to be replaced with the correct reference: usually `/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/`.*

**The problem**

Sourcing `~/.bashrc` in `crontab -e` won't work (at least not on Ubuntu).

Explanation:

- On Ubuntu, `~/.bashrc` has the following (or similar) line at the beginning of the file:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

- This means that if we try to source the `~/.bashrc` file in `crontab`, the rest of the `.bashrc` file will not execute because `crontab` is not running interactively (see another [post on this topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080812/1050912)). **Which means that the `conda` snippet mentioned above will never get executed by `crontab` even if we source `~/.bashrc`.**

## **_________ Working solution _________**

The solution I have found is to copy the `conda` snippet to a separate file.

#### **1. Copying the `conda` snippet from `~/.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc_conda`**

Copy the snippet mentioned above to another file, for example `~/.bashrc_conda`.

Ensure that:

- The user running the cronjob has permission to read this file.
- Other users cannot write to this file (security risk).

#### **2. In `crontab -e` insert 2 lines to run `bash` instead of `sh` and to source `~/.bashrc_conda`**

Run `crontab -e` and add the following 2 lines **before the cronjob**:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc_conda
```

Explanation:

- `SHELL=/bin/bash` means that `crontab` will run the cronjobs via `bash` instead of `sh` (default). [See post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94459/383339).
- `BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc_conda` sources the `conda` snippet to `bash` run by `chrontab`. See [post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/cron-doesn%27t-source-bashrc-how-to-do-this-for-all-commands-in-crontab-4175603604/#post5695479) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48299319/11750716).

#### **3. In `crontab -e` insert in the cronjob line `conda activate my_env;` before the desired `.py` script execution**

Example of entry for a script that would execute at noon 12:30 each day within the desired conda environment:

```
30 12 * * * conda activate my_env; python /path/to/script.py
```

Notice `conda activate my_env;` before the command to run the Python interpreter.

## **_______________**

#### And *voilà*, it worked.

**Any downsides?**

If the `conda` snippet in `.bashrc` gets updated by a `conda` update, it will of course not be reflected in the separate `.bashrc_conda` file. One may need to check for updates from time to time.

One could also to append `; conda deactivate` at the *end* of that cronjob, but this may be redundant.

Answer (score 23):

I recently switched from [canopy](/questions/tagged/canopy) to Anaconda precisely to get away from having to activate an env in cron jobs.
Anaconda makes this very simple, based on the PATH enviornment variable. (I'm using [miniconda](/questions/tagged/miniconda) not the full Anaconds install but I believe anaconda should work the same way)

There are two different approaches, I've tested;

- Add a shebang in your python script, main.py

  `#!/home/users/user_name/miniconda2/envs/my_env/bin/python`
- Add PATH to the top of your crontab

  `PATH=/home/users/user_name/miniconda2/envs/my_env/bin`

**Update:**

Jérôme's answer and cbarrick's comments are correct.  I just got burned using the above approach in a Conda env which needed `pynco,` which needs the full conda environment to find proper the `nco` commands, such as `ncks, ncrcat.`  Solved by running a bash script from cron which calls conda activate first.

Comment: I implemented your solution in Ubuntu 16 and successfully got Anaconda to run. However, when trying to import PANDAS package in the python script that is run, I get an [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Any thoughts as to why? My bash command setup is pretty straightforward. `PATH=/home/dev/anaconda3/bin`
`python /home/dev/AUTOSIFT/script.sh`

Comment: Don't really understand your question.  script.sh is not a python script. Is this a cron job?  Perhaps you need to first do a conda install pandas.

Comment: A shell command triggers a python script. I figured this out though. The problem was that the .sh needed a PATH variable set when it runs.

Comment: Some packages may register scripts to be run upon activation. Activation also sets environment variables that some packages may depend on. Therefore you should always activate your env with `source activate`. Following this answer may cause problems when using packages like `proj4` or `cartopy`.

Comment: @cbarrick, what would you suggest then?

Comment: Within the cron job, you should `source activate` (or `conda activate` in the new 4.4 release). This will setup the path _and_ run the activation scripts at once.

Comment: @Adestin perhaps you need to add `:/usr/bin:/bin` to the end of your `PATH` to ensure access to system utilities and libraries (note that `$PATH` doesn't work in a crontab file!). I guess pandas will look for other OS commands/libraries than python, and with the PATH truncated as you have, it won't find them. (**this is an edit to a previous erroneous comment, now deleted**)

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I got this error when I ran this line of shell script: `source activate my_env`

`activate: No such file or directory`

So I changed `source activate my_env` to `source /path/to/conda/bin/activate my_env`. Then it starts working.

Comment: this solution is the easiest one!! Thank you~~~

Comment: make sure you are using `bash` (and not sh) while using `source` cmd

Answer (score 2):

## Use a full path to conda

A simple solution that worked for me was to specify a full path to conda in the crontab entry, and to use the `conda run -n <env>` option to execute the command in the required environment. In my case I wanted to launch a command on start up, so my crontab entry looked like this:

`@reboot ~/miniconda3/bin/conda run -n <env> <command>`

where `<env>` and `<command>` are substituted according to your own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2022, I just use a `.bat` in Windows 10 to activate `myenv` and then start my `localhost` or whatever script you need:

```
@echo off
set CONDAPATH=C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3
set ENVNAME=myenv
if %ENVNAME%==base (set ENVPATH=%CONDAPATH%) else (set ENVPATH=%CONDAPATH%\envs\%ENVNAME%)
call %CONDAPATH%\Scripts\activate.bat %ENVPATH%

call cd /d d:/mysite
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach could be a bit simpler and more concise in some cases:

1. find the path of your conda environment

   `conda env list`
2. add this as "PATH" on top of the crontab file:

   `PATH=/Users/your_user_name/opt/anaconda3/envs/your_env/bin`

For more details check this
[tutorial](https://donny-son.github.io/posts/cronjob-with-conda/) (Source)

Answer (score 0):

I think conda has changed, and so none of these solutions work for me anymore, other than the one posted by @James to specify the full path to conda within crontab.

However, sometimes I want to run a full bash script from crontab, and activate a conda environment throughout that script. For that, the solution which worked was to source `conda.sh`, as posted by @effecor here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65183109/1676378.

For me, this means adding the following line to the top of my bash script that is called by cron:

`source /home/chris/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`

Your conda.sh may be located somewhere else.

The underlying issue is explained here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980
As nehaljwani writes: "Functions are not exported by default to be made available in subshells."

Answer (score 0):

U just need to add PATH and use conda run -n command

> PATH=/root/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin:/root/miniconda3/bin:/root/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>
> 5 0 * * * conda run -n my_env python ~/my_project/main.py

easy solution