# CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create a virtual environment using `conda` on Google Colaboratory.
However, I can't activate with the following error.

```
    CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init
```

Three things that I've tried:
One is to add the following code to `~/.bashrc`

```
# >>> conda init >>>
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '$HOME/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "$HOME/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "$HOME/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~
conda create --name XXXXXX python=3.6 -y
conda activate XXXXXX 
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Secondly, I added the following code to `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/bin/:$PATH"
```

Thirdly, I added the following code to `~/.bashrc`

```
. /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

If I try to activate each of them, I get the same error. If anyone knows how to fix it, please share your wisdom.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give the output of `echo $SHELL`. I suspect that your shell does not load `~/.bashrc` - maybe it uses a different file. Also I would recommend to undo all the modifications in `~/.bashrc` and only use `conda init <shell-name>` to modify it - especially the later ones do more harm than good.

Comment: This approach by `conda` is an absolute disaster. Countless hours lost here.

Comment: NOTE: source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate ... then do the usual seems to solve it. usual being conda activate myenv

Answer (score 180):

The answer is here:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980

```
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate my_env
```

Maybe you're also using the wrong anaconda/miniconda path.
Use the one which results from this command:

```
conda info | grep -i 'base environment'
```

:)

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. just get the conda path first from the second command.

Comment: In the commands above, replace ~/anaconda3/ with the path to your miniconda / anaconda installation. You can find that out by running: conda info | grep -i 'base environment'

Comment: But it seems it doesn't work for me...
```!source /root/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
!/root/anaconda3/bin/conda activate maskrcnn_benchmark```
gives
```CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.```

How to fix it?((

Comment: And adding ```export -f conda
export -f __conda_activate
export -f __conda_reactivate
export -f __conda_hashr```
into /root/.bashrc also dosn't work

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Worked on `git bash` on Windows 10

Answer (score 22):

First you have to run

1. Activate base environment like this

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

or

```
source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate
```

2. after that

```
conda init <your terminal type>
```

eg:

```
conda init bash
```

you will get something like

```
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /home/t/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/t/.bashrc
```

3.Close the current terminal window and open it again (reopen basically).
Now if you type `conda activate` it should work

```
t@t:~$ conda activate
(base) t@t:~$ ^C
(base) t@t:~$
```

Comment: I am in a script and can not close/reopen

Comment: Do `source ~/.bashrc` after `conda init bash` .

Answer (score 3):

For me the last answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031430/conda-environment-in-google-colab-google-colaboratory) worked. It's kind of inconvenient but better than nothing... So, if it's necessary to run something in the conda environment, I just put `!source <path_to_activate_function> my_env` before other commands, as follows:

```
!source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate vilbert-mt && conda env list
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when attempting to run `conda init zsh` from within the VSCode terminal. After some exploration, I discovered that conda was changing a version of the `.zshrc` that seems to be specific to VSCode:

`modified      /var/folders/7d/v4z10qpx333_0397n8nrw6pr0000gn/T/vscode-zsh/.zshrc`

Running this directly in a separate terminal solved the problem for me. I suspect the same kind of issue might present itself for any of the supported VSCode shells.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users, this worked:

```
~\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat my_env
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
!activate your_env
```

reference - https://github.com/dataprofessor/code/issues/10#issuecomment-840936481

Answer (score 0):

For `python-conda` installed from AUR I think this command is needed before running `conda activate <env>`:

```bash
source /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed to run `source ~/.bashrc`

[Here the original post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-a-streamlit-app-using-an-amazon-free-ec2-instance-416a41f69dc3)

```
sudo apt-get update
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p ~/miniconda
echo "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/miniconda/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use directly the Anaconda PowerShell. The command "conda activate" works just fine